# Create custom event in c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

i have a problem like this. I have a treeview, treeviewitems was created by my code when the application running. i want to create a event when i click the treeviewitem. How could i do it ? 
This is my code

```
            TreeViewItem tvitem = new TreeViewItem();
            tvitem.Header = namhoc;
            tvSoDoNamHoc.Items.Add(tvitem);
            List<Khoi> dskhoi = TruyCapDuLieu.Instance.getTableKhoi().ToList();
            foreach (Khoi k in dskhoi)
            {
                TreeViewItem tvitems = new TreeViewItem();
                tvitems.Header = k.TenK;
                tvitem.Items.Add(tvitems);
                List<Lop> dslop = TruyCapDuLieu.Instance.getLopForAutoInsertLop(Member.Instance.SetNamHoc, k).ToList();
                if (dslop.Count != 0)
                {
                    foreach (Lop l in dslop)
                    {
                        TreeViewItem tvitems2 = new TreeViewItem();
                        tvitems2.Header = l.TenL;
                        tvitems.Items.Add(tvitems2);                        
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: Try using the **[Selected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem.selected?view=netframework-4.7.2)** event.

Comment: The question is redirected to another link, see response here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613990/create-event-handler-for-treeviewitem-in-wpf/53111807#53111807

Answer (score 1):

The event you want is [SelectedItemChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.treeview.selecteditemchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2)

For an alternative way to handle this, the following code creates a two-way bindable SelctedItem property on the TreeView. You can use this to detect when an item is selected (and set the selected item on the tree from your code).

```
public class perTreeViewHelper : Behavior<TreeView>
{
    public object BoundSelectedItem
    {
        get => GetValue(BoundSelectedItemProperty);
        set => SetValue(BoundSelectedItemProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundSelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BoundSelectedItem",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(perTreeViewHelper),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                OnBoundSelectedItemChanged));

    private static void OnBoundSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.NewValue is perTreeViewItemViewModelBase item)
            item.IsSelected = true;
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged += OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged -= OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged(object obj, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> args)
    {
        BoundSelectedItem = args.NewValue;
    }
}
```

More details on my recent [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/wpf-behaviors-part-2-treeview/).

Comment: Thank for help !